# history is shifted by 5 lines

Tags: bash, command-history, xubuntu, xfce4-terminal

In `.bashrc` I have:

```
HISTSIZE=5000
HISTFILESIZE=10000
```

`wc -l .bash_history` gives `10000` as expected, so when executing `history` immediately after opening the terminal, 5000 lines are printed. However, the top (first) history line is always number 5 and the bottom line is always number 5004 E.g.

```
   5  12/11/18 15:55  ls
   6  12/11/18 17:00  lsblk
[...]
5002  24/05/19 11:52  lsb_release -d
5003  24/05/19 11:56  cat .bashrc
5004  24/05/19 12:00  history
```

There are no multi-line commands in `.bash_history`.

clearly this isn't a major problem, but I'm still interested to know what's going on.

`bash` version: 4.3-14ubuntu1.2

`xfce4-terminal` version: 0.6.3-2ubuntu1